# Date validation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I have a little problem with the Date validation in Laravel.
When I fill the date field with 01/25/2018, what is saved in my database is 2020-01-01, as if "25" was 2 x 12 + 1.

I just would like to save the correct date, with 'd/m/Y' format. Here is my code :

Request :

```
"date" => "required|date",
```

Model :

```
public $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'date'];

public function setDateAttribute($date) {
    $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you are submitting an HTML form and you are not transforming the value of a `<input type="datetime-local">` field manually, the format will be `Y-m-d` or `2018-01-25` for your example.

Answer (score 0):

use `format('d/m/Y')` to set the date format and also change the field of your database to `string (varchar)`.

```
public $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'date'];

public function setDateAttribute($date) {
    $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Date type validation in Laravel

```
Public function index () {
    $rules = [
           'start_date'  => 'date_format:Y-m-d|after:today'
        ];

        if ($this->request->has('start_date') && $this->request->get('start_date') != $this->request->get('end_date')) {
           $rules['end_date'] = 'date_format:Y-m-d|after:start_date';
       } else {
           $rules['end_date'] = 'date_format:Y-m-d|after:today';
       }

       return $rules
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `input` as `date` it will show the dates as per users system date format and will pass the value as mysql format.

```
<input type="date" name="start_date">
```